# Symfony2: is ArrayCollection better than multiple db queries?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

In Symfony2 I have two entities (`Companies` and `Employees`) with a One-to-Many relation (one company can have multiple employees).
Each Employee object has an `id`, a `company_id` (foreign key), a `badge_number`, a `last_updated` datetime field, `name`, etc

Easy, right?
Now comes the tricky part...

Each day I get (from an API) a `$company_upd` array that contains the list of all the companies that updated some of their employees data. Then, for each company in `$company_upd`, I retrieve from the API a `$company_employees_list` array that cointains the new list of employees .

Then I loop through the array to identify any new/updated record that needs to be persisted in my local database. Like this:

```
foreach ($company_employees_list as $employee){

    $local_employee = $repo->findOneBy("badge_number" => $employee["badge_number"];

    //if there is already an employee record with the same badge_number

    if($local_employee){

        //compare the last_updated field to see if this employee record needs to be updated

        if($employee["badge_number"] > $local_employee->getLastUpdated()){

            //update the record and persist to the database
            $local_employee->setSomething($employee["some_value"];

        }

    } else {

         //create a new employee object and persist it to the database
         $new_employee = new Employee();
         $new_employee->setSomething('some_value');
         $em->persist($new_employee);

    }

}

$em->flush();
```

Of course, this approach works fine BUT I'm doing a query foreach employee foreach company!! (to retrieve the corresponding object and update it)

Is it possible (and would it be better) to use the ArrayCollection? I mean: fetch the employees ArrayCollection ONE TIME and then, work with it. Search if there is already an employee record with a specific badge_number and eventually update it and persist it to the database?
So, basically, I would like to do everything I did in the code above but using Array_Collection instead of separate queries.
But only if this new approach is faster/better.

If it is indeed possible (and faster), could you please write some mockup code to better understand HOW to manipulate an ArrayCollection and do what I want?

```
//Fetch the local db employees ArrayCollection
$employees_ar_coll = $company->getEmployees();

//What now???? =)
```

P.s. The API works like this, can't change that.

Comment: Well, this is fore sure the most expensive way.
For starters, you only need to flush once at the end of your loop.
Also, you only need to call persist of the objects are newly created and not retreived or known to the db. Thirdly, if you manage to insert a collection, that would be cheaper, yes.

Comment: I have updated the code above. Is it right? And could you please wirte a bit more about the ArrayCollection and its add/select/remove/update methods (with some examples maybe). Anyway, thank you for the good advice

Comment: don't flush inside the loop. Now you are flushing for each iteration. Flush after the loop has passed. You only need to flush once.

Comment: my bad... I pasted it in the wrong place. Now it should be correct

Comment: You can optimize this one with use of raw SQL and write direct update on employee table (UPDATE EMPLOYER SET FIELD = VALUE WHERE ID = ?). In your example with ORM this is correct way to do that.